# Simple way to package a UWP C++ application for running on a clean Windows 10 machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp

I have just built my first UWP C++ example using Visual Studio. It works when I launch it from within studio, but the generated release .exe doesn't even work on this very machine where I built it - I get the following error:

> This application can only run in the context of an app container.

But even if it did run here, there's a question of packing necessary .dlls and such. I checked this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-deploy-and-debug), but it describes a complicated process with signing with a certificate that I don't have, and I don't even have `.Appx` yet (don't see how to make it).

I'm not releasing the app anywhere, I just need to run it on my other Win 10 PC. What's the simplest way?

Comment: The wizard generated a *<Project Name>_TemporaryKey.pfx* file for you. That serves as the certificate for (local) deployment. See [Packaging UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps) for details. Some of the information is .NET-specific, but most of it applies to native C++ (C++/CX, WRL, C++/WinRT) code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to build an app that can be deployed anywhere is to create a store package from project > Store > create app package

[image: create package]

Select "no" to create a test package and follow the instructions.
Once the build completes, the output folder will contain the appx and an installation script named "Add-AppDevPackage.ps1" to deploy the appx on Windows 10 desktop. To start the script, right-click on it and select "run with PowerShell".

[image: files listing]

The script will deploy on the host your application and all its dependencies.